# Bandwidth distance product formula

Tags: optics

I read the following in one reference: A copper wire (twisted pair), the link traditionally associated with low bit rate transmission, is still in use in the modern data centers transmitting data at 20 Gbit/sec. The secret? it does so only over a few meters (the bandwidth distance product is constant). My question: I know that optical fibers, for example, are used for high data rate transmission over long distances. High data rates means high bandwidth and high carrier frequency. According to the constant bandwidth distance constant principle, we can decrease the carrier frequencies used with optical fibers, and thus increase the transmission distance. My question is: can we use very low frequencies (in the range of kilohertz) with optical fibers to transmit data over very large distances? Of course the bit rate will be very low, but I am asking about the possibility to transmit very low frequencies over optical fibers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because cross posted again despite being made aware not to cross post.

Comment: @DKNguyen that sounds more like a reason to "Flag" the post.